# JavaScript stop to extract html tags

Tags: javascript

I have a bookmarklet javascript application, which is used to extract the html tags from the webpage source html file. However, I do not know that why the javascript application will stop extracting the information, when it meets the following piece of html code:

```
<span class="">
<span class="profileCardAvatarThumb"> 
<a class="hasGlobalHandling"  id="nametag_956648_1"       target="_blank"      data-profile-  
card="true" data-profile-id="51ca7e40e4b013690dce7c08" href="#">    
<span class="hideoff">
Access the profile card for user: Lecturer Zhang
</span>
<img alt="" src="/images/ci/ng/avatar_150.gif">
</a>Lecturer Zhang
</span>
</span>
```

Any help is very very appreciated!!!

Comment: @SRN: being inline doesn't mean you cannot put nested tags. Example: `<a>`

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Could you explain to me in details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's not to you but a reply to another person's comment.

Comment: This seems to be a question about some JavaScript that doesn't work -- so maybe you should post the JavaScript? I don't know how we can debug code that we can't see.

Comment: As for me, there's simply no JavaScript there...